# Associative property with respect to multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a non-abelian group with respect to addition and 
$$ G = \{ g \in \text{Aut}(\Gamma)   \ \ |  \ \  \text{if} \ \  g(y)  \ \ = \ \  y \ \ \text{for some} \ \   y \in \Gamma \text{implies} \ \  y = 0 \ \ \text{or} \ \  g = \text{id} \}  $$

Clearly $G$ is a group action on $\Gamma$ defined by
$$ G \times \Gamma \rightarrow \Gamma $$
$$ (g, x) \mapsto g(x) $$

Choose a subset $B_i$ of the nonzero orbit $O_i$ and choose any representative $b_i$ of $O_i$, then define $B  = \{ b_i : b_i  \in O_i \}$ and define the multiplication on $\Gamma$ by
$$x . y = \begin{cases} 0  & \text{if} \ \  y \notin \cup_{i\in I} B_i  \\
g_y(x) &  \text{if}  \ \    y \in \cup_{i \in I} B_i \end{cases}$$

where $g_y \in G$ such that $g_y(b_i) = y$, $y \in B_i$ which is a unique automorphism sending $b_i$ into $y$ (If $g_1 , g_2 \in G$ such that $g_1(b_i) = g_2(b_i) = y$   $\Rightarrow g_1^{-1}g_2 (b_i) = b_i$ $\Rightarrow g_1 = g_2$).

Let $x, y, z \in \Gamma$. I wanto to show that $x.(y. z) = (x. y). z$. I am unable to show the associativity. any help would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: In your first definition, you say $g(y)=y \Rightarrow g=0$ or $g=\mathrm{id}$. Did you mean $y=0$ instead of $g=0$? The zero map is not an automorphism.

Comment: yes you are right, $y = 0$ .  I willl take take care in future, sorry for this.

Comment: Is each $B_i$ supposed to be an orbit?  As written, it sounds like $B_i\subseteq O_i$ for each $i$ but that doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: In particular, associativity will be false if $y\in B_i$ and $z\in B_j$ for some $i,j$ but $g_z(y)\not\in B_i$, since then $x.(y.z)=x.g_z(y)=0$ but $(x.y).z=g_z(g_y(x))\neq 0$.

Comment: @ Eric: yes,  $B_i \subseteq O_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: why $g_z(g_y(x)) \neq 0$ and also you have choosen $g_z(y) \notin B_i$, but $g_z(y)$  may be belongs to $B_k$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to say that each set $B_i$ is an orbit, since if instead $B_i\subseteq O_i$ for each $i$ as you have written the result need not be true (see my comments).  Let us write $C=\bigcup_i B_i$.

To check that $x.(y.z)=(x.y).z$ you just have to unravel the definitions.  First, if $z\not\in C$ then $(x.y).z=0$ and $x.(y.z)=x.0=0$.  Second, suppose that $y\not\in C$.  Then $(x.y).z=0.z=0$.  We also have $x.(y.z)=x.y'$ for either $y'=0$ or $y'=g_z(y)$.  Either way, $y'\not\in C$ (in the second case we are using the assumption that each $B_i$ is an orbit, so $g_z(y)\in C$ iff $y\in C$).  So $x.y'=0$.

So we may assume that $y,z\in C$.  Say $y\in B_i$ and $z\in B_j$.  Then $(x.y).z=g_z(g_y(x))$, and $x.(y.z)=g_{g_z(y)}(x)$ (since $g_z(y)\in B_i\subseteq C$).  Let $h=g_zg_y$; then it suffices to show that $h=g_{g_z(y)}$.  Since $g_z(y)\in B_i$, we just need to show that $h(b_i)=g_z(y)$.  But by definition, $h(b_i)=g_z(g_y(b_i))=g_z(y)$.  Thus $h=g_{g_z(y)}$, and so $$(x.y).z=h(x)=g_{g_z(y)}(x)=x.(y.z).$$